# Azure DevOps Permissions on Pipeline Artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

Is there a way to configure users to be able to view builds in Azure DevOps but disallow downloading of pipeline artifacts from the build status page (published via PublishPipelineArtifact@1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such permission to prevent downloading artifacts in a pipeline. If you can see the build, you would be able to download the artifacts.

You may submit a suggestion for this request at website below:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21